# Agile/Scrum development: How do you handle "off" day?

Tags: agile, scrum

Agile/Scrum development is a very collaborative development process. e.g. it requires developers to continuously communicate & work closely together day-in day-out.

How do you handle your "off" days? Those days that you just don't have energy, can't think straight, don't really have anything to say at the standup meetings, etc.

Just like how athletes have their off days.

Comment: @Adrian: I'm not sure if you meant that as a joke =p but I will take it literally: no, I mean M-F

Comment: I'm just asking because a day off is usually referred to as the day you don't go to work at all. I do understand your question, but you might get more useful answers with a less misleading subject / question.

Comment: @Adrian: yeah, sorry for the ambiguous question. I tried editing in hopes that it's clearer.

Comment: Some days I have a hard disk problem on my laptop or have to repair the SVN database, or have to help out a co-worker outside the team, or there is a fire alarm. All these are valid reasons for being in work but not working on your planned tasks, and I don't see that having an "off day" is really any different to that.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Answer (score 20):

I don't think there should really be a day where you don't have anything to say at the standup meeting.  Every standup meeting should be used to let the rest of the team know whether or not you met the prior day's commitments.

One problem that I have seen on a lot of agile teams is that the developers don't make concrete commitments on a daily basis, so the daily stand-ups aren't all that effective.  If that is an issue, make sure everyone in attendance is setting out concrete goals on a daily basis that can objectively be communicated the next day as either done or not done.

To the rest of your question, I think it is perfectly acceptable to go into a daily stand-up and say that you didn't meet the prior day's objective because you had an off day and use the meeting as an opportunity to make new commitments.  If there was a reason why you had an off day that could be clearly identified as an impediment (e.g. too many interruption, unclear requirements/objectives, dev environment frustrations), those reasons should be reported to the whomever is leading the stand-ups (scrum master) because it is their responsibility to make sure those impediments are addressed.

Comment: thank you for your insightful answer.

Comment: Having nothing to say at a stand-up meeting would mean that you did nothing yesterday, had no obstacles and aren't going to do anything today!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't get anything done, say you couldn't focus and didn't get anything done at the standup meeting. The Scrum Master should try to find out of there is some factor that's distracting you, and try to remove it for you.

Also, if these "off days" are semi-frequent occurrences, try to figure out how often they occur, and include them in your estimates. Scrum is about what's really going on. It's about real timelines. If you know you have 4 off days in 4 weeks, then you should only be claiming 4 days a week worth of work, not 5. (That being said, it's possible that what you can do in 4 days is the same as what someone else can do in 5 days).

Comment: I agree the best approach is to talk about these "off days" as a team. Find out the root cause. Is the task appropriate for the developer? Be open and direct in your communication.

Answer (score 5):

**Pair programming makes it easier to handle.** At least with pair programming, somebody else is there to catch your mistakes early.

**Pick a different task/story to work on** - so that you get a change on scene. Maybe you've been on the same user story too long.

**Gold Cards - (or "fedex days")** - where you can work on anything you want: http://www.planningcards.com/iterex/papers/InnovationAndSustainabilityWithGoldCards.pdf What's noticeable about "gold cards" is that the team that introduced them found that they didn't cause a drop in productivity. This would suggest that it's better to take somebody out of the process on an off day and let them do something constructive of their own choosing than let them work unproductively.

Comment: definitely +1 for mentioning pair programming. I can't tell you enough how much different it feels to work with another developer. It just helps energize you, and also helps bounce off ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you're running the meetings, many people opt for the "Daily Scrum" whilst working on projects, but often they are time wasters and unnecessary. Structure your meetings around when things are completed, if you're completing and re-assigning tasks everyday, then yes, a daily meeting is a good thing, but realistically you can schedule and discuss a number of tasks in one meeting and then re-visit later in the week. Ideally the most efficient meetings usually consist of one weekly meeting (Monday) and quick progress catch up (Wednesday - Thursday). If you're the project manager, insist that team members respond to you directly when they complete work before the next meeting takes place. If you're holding official daily meetings, you're likely burn out with in a month! (and so are your staff). If you have to do daily meetings, make them quick catch ups, set at the same time everyday and only offer the most relevant information and only have one proper meeting during the week. If you'd like to know what to do on your "off days", I can only suggest that you cancel the meeting, take a Berocca, walk around the block, complete your filing and actually do some work instead of holding relentless meetings for a change.

Answer (score 1):

G'day,

As mkedobbs mentioned, you should mention it in the stand-up meeting.

Maybe you need to look at what's making you have an "off" day and communicate that with your team members.

- **Is it due to you banging your head against a problem and you're losing motivation?** Mentioning it in the stand-up may reveal another team member who has previously come up against the problem. They have maybe even solved it, or their experiences and observations may be slightly different to yours but the combination of two heads may solve the issue for both of you.
- **Is it due to your user story turning out to be much bigger than expected and you're feeling overwhelmed?** Raising the issue in the stand-up will help resolve the problem. Maybe this particular user story should be considered a user theme or even a user epic and needs to be broken down into several user stories.
- **Is it because the user story you finished up with is not what you normally do?** Discussing this in the stand-up may uncover team members that do have experience in the particular area covered by the user story. And those team members may be able to provide pointers to help you, maybe directly with the work itself, or with some other resources to help you come up to speed.

These are just a few reasons as to why your "off" day may be directly due to your current work. But definitely don't just stay silent though! Mention it at the stand-up so that any potential problems may be addressed sooner rather than later.

HTH

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I have off days.  My team has off days.

If it is happening a lot or if it is the same people, then root cause and action is needed.  This might be a good topic for a retrospective if the whole team is affected or one-on-one if it is an individual.

As for the answer, you are part of a team.  The team picks up the effort, just like any other issue.  If you team has issues with this, you probably don't have a well formed team and just have a bunch of individuals fending for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Generally at the start of an "off" day, it isn't clear that the day will go badly.  It is only after a few stumbles that it becomes clear that it isn't going to be a good day.  I'd still try to get something done but sometimes the progress is minuscule.  The following day's stand-up is when to say, "Yesterday, I didn't get much done.  I had an off day," or something similar to note that I do recognize that things didn't go well and I'd try to do better today.

Sometimes I'd change what I'm doing that day, as that can sometimes help.  I have had times where I get a few off days in a row, which generally is indicative of needing to take a personal or vacation day and try to recharge myself to get back in the saddle again.